# How to exclude repository from changelog

Tags: jenkins

I have a freestyle Jenkins job with multiple git repositories.

I want Jenkins to ignore one of the repositories when generating the changelog for the build (such as for sending out emails or updating relevant Jira issues).

Is it possible to exclude one of the repositories from the changelog?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up working around this problem myself by removing the the repository from the SCM section of my Jenkins job and writing a script to clone and checkout the repository as a build step.